# Difficult order / group by / count

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got 3 simple tables, but my query is difficult

Sellers table :

```
seller_id | name
1           john
2           paul
5           fred
6           robert
etc ...
```

Transactions table (only 3 values for the moment) :

```
trans_id | name
1          BUY
2          SELL
3          EXCHANGE
```

Operations table :

```
seller_id | trans_id | datetime
2           1          ....
2           2          ....
6           1          ....
2           3          ....
6           1          ....
```

This tables records all the sellers' transactions and their moment.

I would like to obtain, in the last day, or in a time interval

- seller name, number of buy-transaction order by number of buy-transaction in the interval
- seller name, number of buy-or-sell-transaction order by number buy-or-sell-transaction in the interval

I've tried many things, strange things taht mysql does'nt like, but I can't succeed ... thanks !

Comment: You want to count per seller, so your query should `GROUP BY seller_id`. And you'd limit the transaction type in the `WHERE` clause of course. Have you got this far? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: You tried *many things* . Care to show, *what* you tried but didn't work?

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand what are you looking for, but is not something like this?
`SELECT S.NAME, COUNT(O.TRANS_ID) FROM OPERATIONS O JOIN SELLERS S ON O.SELLER_ID = S.SELLER_ID  WHERE O.DATETIME BETWEEN <DATE1> AND <DATE2> GROUP BY S.NAME ORDER BY 2`

Comment: When you say "seller name, number of buy-transaction order by number of buy-transaction in the interval" do you mean the 2nd column should be the total number of buy-transaction" for that seller, regardless of the interval? (basically, is the interval only taken into account in the `order by`, or for the `count()` column too?

Comment: The core is something like `elect sellers.name, count(sellers.trans_id) from operations
join sellers on sellers.seller_id = transactions.seller_id
join transactions on transactions.trans_id = operations.trans_id
where transactions.name in ("BUY", "SELL")
group by  ...
order by count(sellers.trans_id) ` but all I add is not accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution for your first query, ie "seller name, number of buy-transaction order by number of buy-transaction in the interval" :

```
SELECT 
     S.name,
     COUNT(1) AS total
FROM operations O
JOIN sellers S on O.seller_id = S.seller_id
JOIN transactions T on O.trans_id = T.trans_id
WHERE O.datetime >= CURDATE() AND T.name = 'BUY'
GROUP BY S.name
ORDER BY total
```

Obviously, the second query is nearly the same, the where clause just changes a little, see the following :

```
SELECT 
     S.name,
     COUNT(1) AS total
FROM operations O
JOIN sellers S on O.seller_id = S.seller_id
JOIN transactions T on O.trans_id = T.trans_id
WHERE O.datetime >= CURDATE()-1 AND T.name IN ('BUY','SELL')
GROUP BY S.name
ORDER BY total
```

To be honest you could even remove the join with transactions table and use O.trans_id in your where clause.

[**SEE DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ebba0a858e886fb6509a001da43c2071)

Comment: Many thanks Gosfly ! This `count(1) as total`....  I wouldn't have succeeded

Comment: @troubadour: `count(1)` is just an obfuscated way of a mere `count(*)`, i.e. count rows. Your own `count(sellers.trans_id)` works just as fine, but should rather be `count(operations.trans_id)` in which case you could even outer join the operations table and thus include sellers with a zero count. All your own query was really missing seems to be the appropriate `GROUP BY` clause and the date range restriction.

Comment: `WHERE date(O.datetime) >= CURDATE()` is the same as `WHERE O.datetime >= CURDATE()` by the way. Only worse, because applying the date function may hinder the DBMS from using an index.

Comment: Oh yes you are perfectly right, let me fix this. Thanks @ThorstenKettner.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner thanks, you're right, just an error when writing.
here one must understand the underlying link beween count() and where clause .. the sum is done here

Answer (score 1):

Here solution for your first query

```
Select a.name, a.count from
(select seller.name name, Count(Transaction.Tran_id) count
from seller, Transaction, Operation
where seller.Seller_id = Operation.Seller_Id
and Transaction.Tran_id = Operation.Tran_id
and Transaction.Tran_id=1
and Operation.datetime between (datetime 1 & datetime2)
group by seller.name) a
order by a.count
```

Second solution is :-

```
Select a.name, a.count from
(select seller.name name, Count(Transaction.Tran_id) count
from seller, Transaction, Operation
where seller.Seller_id = Operation.Seller_Id
and Transaction.Tran_id = Operation.Tran_id
and Transaction.Tran_id in (1, 2)
and Operation.datetime between (datetime 1 & datetime2)
group by seller.name) a
order by a.count
```

Comment: Thanks Vibhor, great too, and best result for an other case !  I investigate .....